# What is the purpose of a constant pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I am a beginner to C++ and have the following question regarding the purpose of pointers where neither the address nor the value that it is pointing to can be changed (`constEverything` in the **example**).

**Example:**

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    int* const constPoint = &i;
    *constPoint = 3; // legal
    constPoint = &j; // illegal
    const int* constVal = &i;
    *constVal = 3; // illegal
    constVal = &j; // legal
    const int* const constEverything = &i;
    *constEverything = 3; // illegal
    constEverything = &j; // illegal
}
```

In the **example** there are different types of pointers. With `constVal` you can change the address and with `constPoint` you can change the underlying value. For `constEverything` you can do neither.

To me the purpose of such a pointer would be to pass things by constant reference. Why should I not just use **const type &val** instead? To me a const reference seems a lot easier and it makes **const type* const val** obsolete.

Comment: A C api has no references. To use libs like libcurl or libtar in your C++ projects you should know how to work with pointers.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik. I did not know that. Makes sens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant pointers are useful for two principal reasons.

1. `this` is a `const` pointer in a `const` member function.
2. A `const` pointer can also be set to `nullptr`.

My first point is somewhat circular, `this` *could* have been a reference type or a `const` reference type, but references arrived late into the C++ standard, and any changes would have been breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are remainders of the C programming language. C didn't have references, thus pointers were your only option. Now you are free to use references in C++, but if you have to work with a C API (e.g. Win32 API) you will have to use pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to pass arguments: *by value*, and *by reference*. Constness is especially relevant when passing by reference: it indicates whether the passed argument can be changed.

In that respect, there are two ways you can pass *by reference* in C++: using a reference (&) or using a pointer (*). In C, there is only one way to pass *by reference*: using a pointer (*).

So if you allow passing references as `const type &val` in C++, the equivalent in C would have to use pointers, leading to `const type * const val`. You could ommit the constness of the pointer itself (which in my experience is often seen in C APIs).

Regardless of personal preferences, since C code should also be valid C++, a pointer based version is required as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code :

```
#include <iostream>

struct BigObject {
    int a{};
};

BigObject* createBigObj()
{
    bool allGood = true ; // some real work here

    if ( allGood ) 
        return new BigObject{1};
    else 
        return nullptr;
}

void readBigObj(BigObject const * const bigOb)
{
    if (bigOb)
        std::cout << bigOb->a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto* big = createBigObj();
    readBigObj(big);

    return 0;
}
```

The funciton :

```
void readBigObj(BigObject const * const bigOb)
```

Can't take a `const BigObject&` because the object can be null. The function didn't change the value of the pointor nor the value, both should be `const`

Tada! A reason of const value const pointor :)